# structs, Cities and distances, graphs and Dijkstras in C

Tags: c, data-structures

I'll try to keep this simple and not waffle. I'm a relative beginner and i'm having trouble with the concept of what to do for my assignment. I've been given a text file with a start city, end city and the distance between them. i have to use that text file and construct a program in C which sorts them into a heap and uses Dijkstras to find the shortest distance. The code i have written so far is to read the text file and print it,

```
struct intertown_distance{
char start[60];
char end[60];
int distance;};

void fileRead(struct intertown_distance data){
int i;
FILE *fptr;
fptr = fopen("data.txt", "r");

if (fptr == NULL)
{
     printf("Can not open the file\n");
     exit(1);
}

for(i=0; i<40; i++)
{
   fscanf(fptr, "%s %s %d", data.start, data.end, &data.distance);
   printf("%s %s %d \n", data.start, data.end, data.distance);
}

fclose(fptr);}
```

I'm new to C, structs, the idea of nodes and all these different types of data structures, so i was wondering if anyone could help by sharing some knowledge or some links to reading material that could help me understand and get me started. I'm struggling to get help from anyone else on the course and even the lab leaders/lecturers.

many thanks

Comment: Could you be more specific? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: i'm stuck with how to go about using the information provided in the text document to set up the nodes or arrays to implement the graphs and Dijkstras algorithm. I'm sorry if that still isn't clear. I think my lack of understanding as a whole is making it difficult for me to pin point exactly what i'm asking which is no use for anyone really. sorry

Answer (score 1):

so far so good, your code seems to work pretty well.

I just made a few changes. hope you don't mind.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* max size of lines */
#define MAXCHARLINE 1000
/* max size of city names */
#define MAXCHARCITY 60

typedef struct intertown_dist_s
{
  char start[MAXCHARCITY];
  char end[MAXCHARCITY];
  unsigned int distance;
}intertown_dist_t;

int main() {
  FILE *fp;
  char str[MAXCHARLINE];
  char* filename = "data.txt";
  intertown_dist_t data;

  fp = fopen(filename, "r");
  if (fp == NULL)
  {
    printf("Could not open file %s",filename);
    return 1;
  }
  while (fgets(str, MAXCHARLINE, fp) != NULL)
  {
    sscanf(str, "%s %s %d", data.start, data.end, &data.distance);
    printf("%s %s %d \n", data.start, data.end, data.distance);
  }
  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

you can then store the parsed intertown_distance elements in a static array :

```
#define MAXINTERTOWN 30
...
intertown_dist_t data[MAXINTERTOWN];
```

you can also store them a dynamic array using linked list :
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generic-linked-list-in-c-2/
This could be a good start since linked list struct integrate the node notion.
you can also take a look at this: [Linked list with multiple parent and child nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18140460/linked-list-with-multiple-parent-and-child-nodes)

Comment: nice one thank you! will definitely check out the links. very much appreciated